# WOODMART theme in wordpress : Portfolio single project > related projects displayed

Tags: wordpress, portfolio

On a page of a project in protfolio single project, 3 related projects are displayed in the carrousel.
I would like to have :

6 projects displayed on deskstop
6 projects displayed on tablet wide
4 projects displayed on tablet high
2 projects displayed on mobile

Probably I need code snippet.
Thanks a lot
fred

I tried this code :

function wd_shortcode_wd_owl ( $atts = array(), $content = null ) {
$output = $class = $autoplay = '';

```
    $parsed_atts = shortcode_atts( array_merge( wd_get_owl_atts(), array(
        'slider_spacing' = 30,
        'dragEndSpeed' = 600,
        'el_class' = '',
    ) ), $atts );

    extract( $parsed_atts );

    $class .= ' ' . $el_class;
    $class .= ' ' . wd_owl_items_per_slide( $slides_per_view );

    $carousel_id = 'carousel-' . rand(100, 999);

    $parsed_atts['carousel_id'] = $carousel_id;
    $parsed_atts['custom_sizes'] = array(
        'desktop' = 6,
        'tablet_landscape' = 5,
        'tablet' = 5,
        'mobile' = 2,
    );
    $owl_atts = wd_get_owl_attributes( $parsed_atts );
    
    ob_start(); ?
        <div id="<?php echo esc_attr( $carousel_id ); ?>" class="wd-carousel-container slider-type-portfolio wd-rs- wd-portfolio-holder wd-carousel-spacing-30<?php echo esc_attr( $slider_spacing ); ?>" <?php echo ( $owl_atts ); ?>
            <div class="owl-carousel wd-owl<?php echo esc_attr( $class ); ?>" >
                ?php echo do_shortcode( $content ); ?
            </div>
        </div>
    ?php
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'wd_wd_owl', 'wd_shortcode_wd_owl' );
```